# In Ember pushObject calls supposed callbacks but removeObject does not

Tags: arrays, ember.js, observers

I got the following WorkSpec item controller, which controls checkboxes state:

```
ContractorApp.WorkSpecController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  needs: ['account']
  selected: (->
    work_spec = @get 'content'
    work_specializations = @get 'controllers.account.work_specializations'
    work_specializations.contains work_spec
    ).property()

  selection_changed: (->
    work_spec = @get 'content'
    work_specializations = @get 'controllers.account.work_specializations'

    limit = @get 'controllers.account.specialization_limit'

    if @get( 'selected' ) && work_specializations.get('length') < limit
      work_specializations.pushObject work_spec
    else
      work_specializations.removeObject work_spec
    ).observes('selected')
```

As you see work_specializations is the parent's set of work specializations:
I want to control (work_specializations.get('length') < limit) the addition of an element to the array.

The problem here that I got observer in the model contained the work_specializations array:

```
ContractorApp.ContractorProfile = DS.Model.extend
  work_specializations: DS.hasMany "work_specialization"
  on_spec_change: ( ->
    ws_ids = @get( 'work_specializations').map (ws)->
      ws.get 'id'
    @set( 'work_specialization_ids', ws_ids )
  ).observes 'work_specializations'
```

For some reason the call of 'work_specializations.pushObject work_spec' calls the model's callback but its counterpart removeObject does not. Any ideas why?

Comment: Don't you need to declare the dependencies for `selected`, especially `controllers.account.work_specialization`, inside the call to `property`?

Comment: @torazaburo No, the prop is bound to the control's (checkbo) state. Also the selection_changed successfully called whenever I check or uncheck the boxes. The question is why even if 'work_specializations.removeObject work_spec' is called the property observer on the model isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're observing the collection itself, not items being added or removed.  It's likely that the first change is triggering the observes to fire for the first time.

```
on_spec_change: ( ->
  ws_ids = @get( 'work_specializations').map (ws)->
    ws.get 'id'
  @set( 'work_specialization_ids', ws_ids )
).observes 'work_specializations.[]'
```

Comment: Thank you. The other day I added '.length' to 'work_specializations' alike you did and it worked on both adding and removing. Still don't understand why it worked on adding (not just the first time! Worked as expected every time!)